# linux high resolution posix timer delay due to multiple processes

Tags: linux, timer, posix, timedelay

In the following posted code, i have used high resolution posix timer 'timer_create' to call the callback function periodically after every 1 milllisecond(posix timer says that it can provide microsecond delay). If i run only one instance of the executable, it works fine and the callback gets called every 1 millisecond, but if i run multiple instances of the same executable (say 10 instance and in each instance i have configured 1 millisecond periodic timer), there is a delay of around 2 to 4 millisecond in calling the callback function in each instance. Following is the program.

```
            #include <stdio.h>
            #include <stdlib.h>
            #include <unistd.h>
            #include <time.h>
            #include <signal.h>
            #include <errno.h>

            #define errExit(msg)    do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }while(0)

            unsigned long long old_time = 0, diff = 0;
            timer_t timerid;
            struct sigaction sa;
            struct sigevent sev;
            struct itimerspec its;

            static void timer_cb(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc)  
            {
                unsigned long long time = 0;
                struct timeval tv;

                gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
                time = (tv.tv_sec * 1000000) + tv.tv_usec;

                if(old_time != 0)
                {
                    diff = time - old_time;
                    if (diff > 1100)
                    {
                        printf("%lld\n",diff);
                    }
                }
                old_time = time;    
            }


            int main (void)
            {   
                sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
                sa.sa_sigaction = timer_cb;
                sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
                if (sigaction(SIGRTMIN, &sa, NULL) == -1)
                            errExit("sigaction");

                /* Create the timer */

                sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
                sev.sigev_signo = SIGRTMIN;
                sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerid;

                if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sev, &timerid) == -1)
                            errExit("timer_create");

                its.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
                its.it_value.tv_nsec = 1000 * 1000;

                its.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
                its.it_interval.tv_nsec = 1000 * 1000;

                if (timer_settime(timerid, 0, &its, NULL) < 0)
                {
                    errExit("timer_settime");
                }

                while(1)
                {
                    sleep(10);
                }

                return 0;
            }
```

Is there anything wrong in above code which is causing the delay or is there any other method to achieve a 1 millisecond delay properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. Linux just doesn't support your use case out of the box. Linux isn't a realtime operating system, and running multiple tasks with millisecond accuracy, is definitely in the realm of real time systems. There are realtime extensions for Linux, try looking at the [RTWiki](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page).

Comment: We have tried the above code for 100 millisecond, even in that case with multiple instances, it gives error of about 50+ millisecond, so does that mean it works only in seconds domain.

Comment: As I wrote, Linux is not a realtime kernel, so you cannot expect accurate timing. The scheduler simply does not support it -- unless you go for one of the realtime extension